# How to build OsgEarthQt with OsgEarth2.10?

Tags: osgearth

OSG3.4.1        OSGEarth2.10    win7 vs2015 x64
How to build OSGEarthQT?
I use the source code osgEarthQt,but there is no install project after construction，Lib file not found

Answer (score 0):

osgEarthQt has been removed from the cmake files so will not build in osgEarth 2.10.

You either need to use an older version of osgEarth or add support back into the cmake files for building osgEarthQt.

I have been adding support back into the cmake files locally to build osgEarthQt.

Sadly the developers no longer support Qt.